# Split string in Go while preserving escaped spaces

Tags: go

I can split a string with `strings.Split`:

```golang
strings.Split(`Hello World`, " ")
// ["Hello", "World"]  (length 2)
```

But I'd like to preserve backslash escaped spaces:

```golang
escapePreservingSplit(`Hello\ World`, " ")
// ["Hello\ World"] (length 1)
```

What's the recommended way to accomplish this in Go?

Comment: The recommended way is to write code which does that. Or do you seek some 3rd party library which does that?

Comment: Go's regex engine doesn't support Perl syntax, and the standard library doesn't have a function to do this. You'd have to resort to some string manipulation trick (likely inefficient) or roll your own solution, which you can optimize based on the invariants of your particular use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since go does not support look arounds, this problem is not straightforward to solve.

This gets you close, but leaves a the trailing space intact:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`.*?[^\\]( |$)`)
split := re.FindAllString(`Hello Cruel\ World Pizza`, -1)
fmt.Printf("%#v", split)
```

Output:

```
[]string{"Hello ", "Cruel\\ World ", "Pizza"}
```

You could then trim all the strings in a following step.